# Importing JSON into an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, json, import

I'm an aspiring Java programmer looking to use JSON in a project. I was following a programming tutorial (from a book) which asked me to import JSON into my project by using the following line:

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONArray;
```

But this produced an error, so I replaced it with this line:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

This also produces a (different) error:

> The import org.json cannot be resolved

I think the problem is that I don't actually have the JSON library in my Eclipse workspace. How can I do this, so I can use the JSONArray? I found the website for JSON, but am not sure what to download or how or where to install it:

http://json.org/java/

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Download the ZIP file from this [URL](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip) and extract it to get the Jar. Add the Jar to your build path. To check the available classes in this Jar use this [URL](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm).

To Add this Jar to your build path Right click the Project > Build Path > Configure build path> Select Libraries tab > Click Add External Libraries > Select the Jar file Download

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: perfectly fits android json lib when writing unit tests on desktop

Comment: Between your answer and the previous one, I'm confused: do we add a New External Jar, or a new Library?

Comment: Where did you find these links? I spent hours on http://www.json.org/java/index.html which took me to github with source code. But no link to a jar.

Comment: @JohnMerlino here is the JAR catalog on Java2s http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm

Comment: @Imray I unzipped it and then used New External Jar.

Comment: None of the links mentioned in entire post  works anymore, but I found this one usefull to download "jason-simple" jar file. 
   https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/downloads

Answer (score 8):

You should take the json implementation from here : http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ .

- Download the *.jar
- Add it to the classpath (right-click on the project, Properties->Libraries and add new JAR.)

Answer (score 6):

The link of accepted answer is old and can cause [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901969/generify-jsonobject-string-keys) with generics use,

You should download latest jar from [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) github site

Add jar to Java build Path

In existing project in `Order and Export` tab move the new jar, as `json-20180813.jar`, as the first (or above other dependencies with `JSONObject`)

Answer (score 2):

Download json from java2s website then include in your project.
In your class add these
package java_basic;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Download java-json.jar from here, which contains `org.json.JSONArray`

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip

nzip and add to your project's library:
Project > Build Path > Configure build path> Select Library tab >  Add External Libraries > Select the java-json.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Download the json jar from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/). This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

on linux 
pip install library_that_you_need
Also on Help/Eclipse MarketPlace, i add PyDev IDE for Eclipse 7, so when i start a new project i create file/New Project/Pydev Project