# External jar cannot be resolved in eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, json, ubuntu, import, jar

I wrote a simple JsonParser code in java. I downloaded json jar file following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997598/importing-json-into-an-eclipse-project). I included the jar file through,

```
Project Properties-> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external jars
```

But still I get the error, "The import org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved" for the import statements.

This is happening in my Ubuntu machine. But following the same steps, I am successfully able to include the jar and run my program in Windows. But I want  it working in my Ubuntu machine. Should I do anything different ?

I have the jar file in the my project directory. It is also getting listed under Referenced Libraries in Package explorer.

[edit]:
I did a ctrl + shift + O to organize imports in eclipse and the statements

```
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONExceptiop
```

got changed  to,

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject
import org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

with following error,

```
The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined
The method length() is undefined for the type JSONArray
The method getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you downloaded the .jar from here:

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

whereas the imports you had were based on the .jar from here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip

The JSONArray from json-simple does not have a constructor that takes a single string.  Switch .jar files or fix the constructor.