# Getting error when importing json jar in my java file in linux

Tags: java, json, linux, eclipse

This is my java code

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlutoMake {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    }
}
```

and I compile it with this and it compiles without error

```
javac PlutoMake.java -cp java-json.jar
```

Now I copied this project from eclipse from windows, and using that jar it worked fine. I could access all the json functions. But here on linux, when I run it, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
```

If I remove the `throws JSONException` then I can run it. So for some reason I can import the jar but I can't access any of its functions/exceptions without crashing my program...

Jar file is from the answer from this link [Importing JSON into an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997598/importing-json-into-an-eclipse-project)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jar file to the runtime classpath

```
java -cp java-json.jar:. PlutoMake
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have create project in eclipse on linux you need configure buildpath inserting the jar