# JSON constructor shown as undefined

Tags: java, json, url, connection

`JSONObject` has an available constructor `JSONObject(String s)` available, but eclipse is telling me it is undefined.

[Documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(org.json.JSONObject,%20java.lang.String[]))

My code is as following:

```
URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +"v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Referer",  "http://google.com");

String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   builder.append(line);
}

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString()); //Error, undefined
```

I have triple checked that all my libraries are the latest and most stable, as well as implemented properly(apart of my build path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add it to your build path?

Here is explained:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8997703/3558900

Comment: I had a different library added as a library so I deleted that and replaced it with the one in that answer. String thing is - I can instantiate the jsonObject but only if I call it by  `org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonData);`

Comment: Never mind - slow night, I imported org.json.*; and it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you now.....

```
URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +"v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("Referer",  "http://google.com");

String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   builder.append(line);
}

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line);
System.out.println(json.toString(4));
```

You did mistake by putting builder inside JSONObject parameter......I hope this should work.....All the best

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this code:

```
static String jsonData;
File json = new File("JSONFile.json");
FileReader fr=new FileReader(json);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
StringBuilder sb=  new StringBuilder();
while((jsonData = br.readLine())!=null)
{
    sb.append(jsonData);
}
jsonData = sb.toString();
br.close();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(4));
```

try to do with this code as I got my result with this.

Comment: Eclipse still gives me "The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined" when I try to instantiate the jsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

In the maven project, I fixed it by adding dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json in pom.xml and it works, I hope it's useful for you