# How to get this json format value?

Tags: android, json

I want to get value from json.But I can't get value.
I want to get 26/08/15 value.

json format:

```
{"Timestamp":["26/08/15"]}
```

*My code :*

```
JSONArray timestamp = jsonObj .getJSONArray("Timestamp");
JSONObject timecatObj = (JSONObject) timestamp.get(0);
Iterator temp = timecatObj.keys();
serverdate = temp.toString();
```

Comment: And your code? I could write the working solution to you, but it's better for you to show you where you made a mistake to learn from it.

Comment: You should use a JSON parser for that...marking it as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract value from Json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332611/how-do-i-extract-value-from-json)

Comment: There are a lot of examples on StackOverflow of how to parse Json for Android, you should poke around a little and see if they can help you first.

Comment: JSONArray timestamp = jsonObj
       .getJSONArray("Timestamp");
     
     JSONObject timecatObj = (JSONObject) timestamp
       .get(0);
     Iterator temp = timecatObj.keys();
     serverdate =temp.toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"Timestamp":["26/08/15"]}, the value of "Timestamp" is a JSONArray, but the element of the JSONArray is String not JSONObject.

So, the code should be :

```
JSONArray timestamp = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Timestamp");
String serverdate = timestamp.optString(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject("{"Timestamp":["26/08/15"]}")
JSONArray arr = ob.optJSONArray("Timestamp",null);
String date = arr.optString(0);
```