# How to get Item1 and Item2 from the response

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Code:

```
string responce = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Home.BaseAddr + "LastID?pass=" + Password);
```

`responce` string is

> { "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "123" }

How to get `Item1` and `Item2` values?

Comment: Maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332611/how-do-i-extract-value-from-json

Comment: In the [documentaton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient) there is an example how to use [GetJsonFormAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync) to parse the result into a record class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imported *System.Net.Http.Json*, you can use the [`GetFromJsonAsync<TValue>(HttpClient, Uri, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-json-httpclientjsonextensions-getfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpclient-system-uri-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method to get the response body as `Response instance`.

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Json;

Response responce = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Response>(Home.BaseAddr + "LastID?pass=" + Password);
```

Otherwise, you should [deserialize the JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize).

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string responceString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Home.BaseAddr + "LastID?pass=" + Password); 

Response responce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responceString);
```

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

string responceString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Home.BaseAddr + "LastID?pass=" + Password); 

Response responce = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(responceString);
```

```cs
public class Response
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the previous solutions, but a straight forward answer would be:

```
 using System.Text.Json;

 ...

 string s = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Home.BaseAddr + "LastID?pass=" + Password); 
 var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Tuple<string,string>>(s);
```

It is simple as that. Because the `Tuple` construct is defined with `Item1`, `Item2` as properties and the deserialializer  would map it on these.

To get the values:

```
string item1 = obj.Item1;
string item2 = obj.Item2;
```

Comment: One also could define custom class to deserialize it to. But that's what i would do ! :)